# Do Full Nodes validate all transactions and make new blocks after all bitcoin are mined?

Tags: full-node, consensus, block

Do Full Nodes validate all transactions after all bitcoin are mined?

A fork of bitcoin core with all coins pre mined would be behaving in this way too I'd imagine..?

Also, would these nodes still create blocks of transactions, if so, why dont full nodes do this now? Is mining only a safety mechanism for a permissionless network?

See this quote at the link below:

> Blockchain Validation vs Blockchain Consensus
>
> It’s important to note that “validation” and “consensus” aren’t the same thing. A Blockchain Validator performs validation by verifying that transactions are legal (not malicious, double spends etc).
>
> However, Consensus involves determining the ordering of events in the blockchain — and coming to agreement on that order.
>
> Essentially, Consensus involves agreeing on the ordering of validated transactions.
>
> The validation precedes the Consensus. We may very well have something that is “valid” that the network does not “agree” upon.

https://medium.com/hupayx/how-are-blockchain-transactions-validated-consensus-vs-validation-ada9c001fd0a

Comment: Please, update the web link, thanks.

Comment: was deleted by the looks of it

Comment: If you find or know any similar post, please add or replace on your question. It is hard to understand your question without some details.

Comment: Have updated, please let me know if you have any other questions about how it all works @CloudCho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do Full Nodes validate all transactions after all bitcoin are mined?

Yes.

> Also, would these nodes still create blocks of transactions

Yes

> if so, why dont full nodes do this now?

Do what? Validation? If so, full nodes certainly do validate now. In fact, full nodes validating is what keeps miners in check.

> Is mining only a safety mechanism for a permissionless network?

Mining is the mechanism in which the ordering of transactions is determined. It's sole purpose is to dictate which transaction came first in the event of a "double spend" and allow everyone to agree that that transaction was first. It is an integral part of achieving consensus. Mining doesn't actually validate anything; just that whatever goes into a block, and the block itself, must be valid, so miners should be validating incoming transactions before including them in a block.

Comment: Oh so MINERS are still needed and are the ones who get rewarded from transaction fees after all bitcoin are mined? So both full nodes and miners are still needed after all mining is done?

Comment: Yes. Blocks will continue to need to be mined and verified after the block subsidy ends. Mining never ends, just the supply of newly generated bitcoin.